# Specified file failed upload test. Wordpress wp_handle_upload()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Contact form 7 plugin for managing website forms.
I'm creating custom register page and form with contact form 7. So when user fill the inputs and submit the button I I call "wpcf7_before_send_mail" hook to register new user with "wp_create_user()".
my problem is on file upload. I need the user upload a file during registration. so I get uploaded file with "$_FILES" and used "wp_handle_upload()" but got error.

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail',function () {
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['file'], ['test_form' => false]);
});`
```

I need get uploaded file with wp_handle_upload(), becuase I need returned data for assigning to the user with update_user_meta();

file_uploads is "ON" in php.ini